# Unable to set org-wide perms for Teams Bot in Teams Admin

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, botframework, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

I have a teams notification bot that I am trying to upload to teams admin portal. The apppackage uploads just fine but when going to the permissions tab, there is no button under "Org-wide permissions" to add the org-wide perms.

[Teams admin missing button to set org-wide perms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pd5WZ.png)

We need to be able to grant org-wide perms to auto install the app for all users in the organization.

The app does show for users under the "built for your org" section of the apps page in teams, however when clicking "add" an error pops up saying "Something went wrong".

I have tried deploying a brand new project with no edits created by teamsfx which faces the same issue as my custom bot.

Microsoft do have this down as a known issue but with no provided solution.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the below permission
Goto Admin Center->Teams App->permission policies
[image]

Also,You must be a global admin to do this. This option isn't available to Teams service admins.
[image]

Reference Document-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/app-permissions-admin-center#grant-org-wide-admin-consent-to-an-app

Comment: This is my current setup already. My custom tab app has the option to review permissions and consent but just not the bot

Comment: The ability to review permissions and grant consent isn't available for all third-party apps. Typically, the third-party apps are registered in Azure Active Directory when the apps request permissions. Instead of the View details link, you'll see -- in the Permissions column.
This is known issue.
Currently, we do not have any ETA or Update for this issue.